# Closed range doesn't imply closed graph

Tags: functional-analysis

An operator between two norm linear space has closed range , then the graph of T is also closed.
I think the above statement is false. But I can't think of a counter example.
If I can show there is a unbounded operator between two Banach space with closed range, then it's done.(Using closed graph theorem).
Any help?

Comment: Surely any unbounded functional on a Banach space does the trick?

Comment: with closed range

Comment: Functionals (i.e. linear maps from the space to the field) automatically have closed range (they are either the $0$ map or are surjective).